# ie7 css html padding issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, padding

hi 
i've encountered a really annoying problem
i'm about to create a imagegallery as can be seen here
http://freeri.freehostia.com/test/

the issue here is that in all later browsers they take in count
that the element before the pagination buttons has padding therefor
the page buttons get placed accuratly 70px beneath last row of images
while ie7 does not so it get's placed only after what margin i've given
the buttons that is 10px beneath

screenshots can be seen here
http://browsershots.org/http://freeri.freehostia.com/test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
.last{
float:none;
margin-bottom:70px;
margin-left:0;
}
```